# How to map // to ~/?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, key-binding

Is it possible to remap ~/ to //?

I want to be able to do something like cat //something.txt and have it be running cat ~/something.txt

Or if this isn't possible, mapping ~ to something easier to type like perhaps just `

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `~/.inputrc`, add:

```
$if Bash

"`": "~/"

$endif
```

Binding `//` is possible, but it can cause some confusion, since the first `/` wouldn't be shown on screen until the entire binding was entered.

Comment: Also, `//` already has a defined meaning: It's equivalent to `/`, which you *really* don't want to override.